# Changing scrollspeed of jscrollpane

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ to make a custom scrollbar for a part of my website and I was wondering if it's possible to change the scrollspeed of the mousewheel.

I don't know if it's any use, but jscrollpane uses this plugin to enable mouse scrolling; http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `mouseWheelSpeed` option provided by jscrollpane.

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
    mouseWheelSpeed: 50
});
```

Ref: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html